# BLOB inserts correctly into DB but not showing in HTML

Tags: php, html, database, image, blob

I have a dropdown where i show an image and a name from DB, now i'm saving this image and name back into the the database (phpmyadmin) into another table. My problem is that the image is being saved correctly into the DB since i downloaded the image and converted it to make sure it's working. The problem is that on the PHP page when doing base64_encode the image the value is not the same as that of the database. Could someone help me point out the problem. Thanks

**Table showing the image**

```
<tbody>
<?php
   while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
       $matchday = $row['matchday'];
       $competition = $row['competition'];
       $home_logo = $row['home_logo'];
       $home_team = $row['home_team'];
       $away_logo = $row['away_logo'];
       $away_team = $row['away_team'];
       $date = $row['date'];
       $time = $row['time'];
       $stadium = $row['stadium'];
       $date_time = $row['date_time'];
                                        
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$date_time.'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$matchday.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$competition.'</td>';
       echo '<td class="imagesize">'."<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($home_logo)."'/>".'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$home_team.'</td>'; 
       echo '<td class="imagesize">'."<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($away_logo)."'/>".'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$away_team.'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$date.'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$time.'</td>'; 
       echo '<td>'.$stadium.'</td>'; 
       echo '</tr>';
    }
 ?>
```

**Form where i have the Dropdown**

```
<div class="form-group p-3">
    <label for="input_hometeam">Home Team</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="input_hometeam" name="input_hometeam" onchange="document.getElementById('output_home').src = this.value; document.getElementById('input_stadium').value = $(this).find(':selected').data('stadium')">
       <?php
          while ($row = $home_team->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
          {
               $hometeamlogo = $row['logo'];
               $hometeamstadium = $row['stadium'];
               $hometeamname = $row['team_name'];
               echo "<option te_name='$hometeamname' value='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($hometeamlogo)."' data-stadium='$hometeamstadium'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
               }
       ?>
     </select>
     <input type='hidden' id="home_name" name="home_name" value=""/>
  </div>
  <img id="output_home" name="output_home" src="#" width="250" height="250" style="padding:25px; margin:0 auto;" alt="Team Logo">
```

Option value is the one being sent to the database

**INSERT statement to Database**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    try
    {
        $matchday = $_POST['input_matchday'];
        $date = $_POST['input_date'];
        $leg = $_POST['input_leg'];
        $competition = $_POST['input_competition'];
        $stadium = $_POST['input_stadium'];
        $hometeam = $_POST['input_hometeam'];
        $awayteam = $_POST['input_awayteam'];
        
        $hometeamname = $_POST['home_name'];
        $awayteamname = $_POST['away_name'];
        
        $hometeamlogo = $_POST['input_hometeam'];
        $awayteamlogo = $_POST['input_awayteam'];
                        
        $updateFixtures = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO fixtures (matchday, home_logo, home_team, away_logo, away_team, stadium, leg, competition, date_time) VALUES ('$matchday', '$hometeamlogo', '$hometeamname', '$awayteamlogo', '$awayteamname', '$stadium', '$leg', '$competition', '$date')");
        
        $dbh->errorInfo();          
        $updateFixtures->execute();
        
        header('Location: view_fixtures.php');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
       'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

***UPDATE: If i insert a new row directly from phpmyadmin the image would show correctly***

Comment: If I read the code correctly, it seems like the contents gets saved as a base64 encoded string (with `'data:image/png;base64,` prepended), but you seem to prepend `'data:image/png;base64,` and base64 encode the data again when you output it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So should i remove the `data:image/png;base64,` in the table where i view them?

Comment: If the data already is in the correct format, then yes.

Comment: When i remove it, it still doesnt show nothing.. The `data:image/png;base64,` is being removed when i check in the inspect element

Comment: For some reason the BLOB value is being changed in the html when compared to that of the DB

Comment: You need to check the source to see what it actually renders. Use "view source" instead of "inspect element" since the later don't show you the real response, it shows you how the browser renders it.